# Memory Utilization R h2o

Tags: r, h2o

I'm working on the Titanic. However I've run into a problem where the model no longer runs but instead throws back an error that seems to have something to do with memory allocation.

```
Error: water.exceptions.H2OModelBuilderIllegalArgumentException: Illegal argument(s) for DRF model: DRF_model_R_1542172359909_24373_cv_1.  Details: ERRR on field: _ntrees: The tree model will not fit in the driver node's memory (2.4 KB per tree x 500 > Zero  ) - try decreasing ntrees and/or max_depth or increasing min_rows!
```

Here is my code sample:

```
 y<-"Survived"
x<-setdiff(names(newtrain_imp),y)
rf_mod<-h2o.randomForest(x,y,train_set,
                         nfolds = 10,
                         keep_cross_validation_predictions = T,
                         seed=233,
                         mtries = 8,#sampling default-1 set to al
                         ntrees = 500,
                         max_depth = 12,
                         validation_frame = validate_set,
                         binomial_double_trees = T)
```

Comment: During initiating h2o using h2o.init(max_mem_size = )  here set the amount of RAM you want h2o to utilize.

Comment: Also it will be good if you can provide reproducible example using dput()

Comment: Restarting the session solved it. I wonder how to close this question.

Comment: you can click on marked as answer to close it .

Comment: There's no answer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During initiating h2o using h2o.init(max_mem_size = 8G) here set the amount of RAM you want h2o to utilize.